# why beamer requires multiple compilation to get slide numbers correct?

Tags: beamer, numbering

I don't actually have a real problem, but I'd like to understand why beamer requires multiple compilations to get the slide count right.

I'm writing a presentation, so I often add a new frame, write something, and then compile the presentation to see how it looks. But every time a new frame is added the total number of slides isn't updated, so the last slide shows a `n+1/n` label instead of `n+1/n+1` as I'd expect(where `n` is the previous number of slides).

I've tried to search a bit but I couldn't find anything mentioning this behaviour.

Is this supposed to be the normal behaviour?

edit:
I can reproduce this by doing the following steps:

1. Create a random beamer presentation(using a style that shows the slide count e.g. AnnArbor) with one frame
2. Compile it
3. Add a new frame
4. Compile again and the last slide will show the described behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of last slide is only known when the last slide is produced (TeX reads your input from start to finish, creating pages as it goes). `beamer` writes this information to the `.aux` file as part of the 'tidy up' after the last output page is produced (at `\end{document}`). On the next run, this information is read back *before* the first page is produced (at `\begin{document}`), and is 'read only' during the page creation process. When the number of slides changes, the *previous* number is used during the typesetting process as that's what was read in. Thus you always need a second run to account correctly for a new slide. (The same is true for many other LaTeX values, for example cross-references, the number of the last *page*, ...).